# Add a checkbox in a listview (C#)

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

I'd like to show a listview in a C# application where every row represents a product so the property "view" is set on "detail". One column (the last one) should be a checkbox because it represents if the product is discountinued.

With the checkboxes property set to true, a checkbox appear in the first column so it doesn't work for my application.

How can add the checkbox to the last column? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `Checkboxes` are always associated with the **first** Column. However you change re-order the **display** of the Columns.

All you need to do it go to the Columns designer and set the 1st colum's `DisplayIndex` to the last column's index.

[image]

Or do it in code:

```
listView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = listView1.Columns.Count - 1;
listView1.Invalidate();
```

Note the `Invalidate` which is necessary to enforce the display of the new layout..