# How to display complex result along with a check box in windows forms appl

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I am new to windows form Application.
I have a scenario where i get Name, path of certain files(dynamically) and want to give to user for  selecting the one's they dont need and delete them.
i want it to be displayed in tabular format :-
[image]

Here under delete i want check box which user can click, at the bottom i will create a button which will fetch all selected files and will call delete logic.
How can i achieve this from UI, which layout should i use and how can i create one more element inside it.

Comment: The `ListView` control contains the `CheckBoxes` boolean, which allows you to have a column of checkboxes in the listview; relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45171704/1481699

Comment: Define ColumType for thosde cells. Valid options are Button, Checkbox, ComboBox, Image, Link and TextBox

Comment: You also have the DataGridView control. If you add your file details to a `List<class>` or a DataTable, it's also easier (more direct) to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt.Columns.Add("SI No", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Delete", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "[]", "a", "C:\\a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "[]", "b", "C:\\b" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "[]", "c", "C:\\c" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "[]", "d", "C:\\d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "[]", "e", "C:\\e" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "[]", "f", "C:\\f" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            dataGridView1.CellClick +=new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int row = e.RowIndex;
            int col = e.ColumnIndex;

            if ((col == 1) && (dt.Rows.Count > 0))
            {
                dt.Rows[row].Delete();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

Using a button

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dt.Columns.Add("SI No", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Delete", typeof(Boolean));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, false, "a", "C:\\a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, false, "b", "C:\\b" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, false, "c", "C:\\c" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, false, "d", "C:\\d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, false, "e", "C:\\e" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, false, "f", "C:\\f" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if ((Boolean)(dt.Rows[i][1]) == true)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `dt.Columns.Add("Delete", typeof(bool));`? So the OP gets a CheckBox column.

Comment: I thought that may be a little confusing.  I thought about it for a fraction of a second.

Comment: I'm not sure what *confusing* is referred to. The OP is looking for an UI that allows to select files that will be deleted later. If you delete the Row, that may be confusing. Also, since you're deleting the data from the DataTable, you don't need to reset the DataSource. That may apply to a List of objects.

Comment: Yes, The answers solves design problem which i was facing. Once i have clicked on checkboxes for rows which i want to delete and press button, how can i fetch only rows where the check box was clicked ?